# The holomorphicity of the integral $\int_\Gamma \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z} d\zeta$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $\Omega$ is open in the plane and $K$ is a compact subset of $\Omega$. Let $f:\Omega \setminus K \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic and bounded. Fix $z \in \Omega \setminus K$ and let $\Gamma$ be a cycle in $\Omega \setminus (K \cup \{z\})$ with winding number $1$ and $0$ on $K \cup \{z\}$ and $\mathbb{C} \setminus \Omega$ respectively. Define
\begin{equation}
F(z)=\int_\Gamma \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z} d \zeta.
\end{equation} Is this function $F$ holomorphic in $\Omega \setminus K$ or in $\Omega$?

Comment: Please define cycle (perhaps a well-known term).

Answer (score 0):

Hint

By Cauchy integral formula, $$F(z)=\begin{cases}2i\pi f(z)&z\in Int(\Gamma) \setminus K\\
0&z\in \overline{Int(\Gamma )}^c\\
\text{not well defined}&z\in \Gamma 
\end{cases}$$
where $Int(\Gamma )$ is the interior of $\Gamma $.

Comment: I don't get your point. Do you mean that $F \in H(\Omega \setminus K)$ or $F \in H(\Omega)$? In fact, my guess the answer is $F \in H(\Omega)$, but I can't show this.

Comment: Both of your suggestion are wrong. To be holomorphic, should at least be continuous...@KKWong